# How do I determine which Linux file is biggest from a list of options?

Tags: linux, files, size

```
$ ls -l
drwsrwsrwt 2  caine caine 4096 2017-01-10 13:21 10050
-rw-r--r-- 10 caine caine 4096 2017-01-19 11:29 10051
drwxr-xr-x 20 caine    18 8096 2017-01-19 11:29 10052
drwxr-xr-x 21 11    caine 4096 2017-01-19 11:29 10053
drwxr-xr-x 22 caine    22 4096 2017-01-19 11:29 10054
-rw-r--r-- 14 caine caine   50 2017-01-19 11:29 10055
```

Based on the above , how do I work out which file size is the biggest? I was told the answer is 10051 but I can't figure out why. Is there a specific method I can use to work out which file is biggest given only the information above?

Answer (score 11):

`ls -l` outputs 7 columns: type & permissions, number of links, owner, group, size, modification time, and name. (This is documented for GNU ls in the info page; see `info ls`, then pick "What information is listed" from the menu, and scroll down to `-l`. Alternatively `info ls 'long ls format'` should take you there directly).

So you look at the first column (type & permissions), the first letter tells you the type: you have `d` for directories and `-` for ordinary files. So there are only two files: 10051 and 10055. Then you look at the 5th (size) column and one is 4096 bytes, the other is 50 bytes — it's clear which is larger.

Of course, all those directories may contain quite a few files, and the total sizes of those files may be larger. `ls` shows the size of the directory itself (if you think about it, it makes sense that "what is in a directory" is data, and thus must be stored somewhere, though on Unix the *names* of files are stored as part of the directory too), not of its contents—one of the directories itself (10052) is bigger.

If you want to know the sizes of directories, including the files and subdirectories (recursively) they contain, `du` is the command to use.

Comment: +1 for being the only answer satisfying "Based on the above "

Answer (score 5):

```
# /bin/ls -1sSr | tail -1
```

Sorted list based on size, then show only the biggest at the end of the list.

Answer (score 4):

Since you mentioned Linux, I assume you're using GNU Coreutils version of `ls`.

From `info ls` we know that `ls -l` will output

> "...file type, file mode bits, number of hard links, owner name, group name, size, and timestamp (*note Formatting file timestamps::), normally the modification time.

So by looking at 5th column - that's the file size, and of course we could parse output of `ls -l`  with `awk` or any other tools, but 1) [parsing ls is bad idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), and 2) [size of files that represent devices will be absent in GNU ls](https://askubuntu.com/q/727728/295286).

As such, I would recommend the alternative:

```
$ find -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec du -b {}  \; | sort -k1,1 -n  | tail -n 1
```

This will filter files, run `du` for each one of them, and sort the output numerically. Last line is the largest file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `du` command:

```
du -a $PWD | sort -n -r
```

The first output is the working directory

Comment: The user is asking about files, not directories.